# How to create an unnested IE11 media query?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to support IE11 in my grid-site, and I have -ms-grid code in one media query. I want to activate -ms-grid only on screens larger than 767px.

This works:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active){
```

I will get -ms-grid code in IE11 with that, and only in IE11, but this doesn't work:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active), (min-width:767px){
```

It doesn't turn off when I resize the screen.. I have tried a few different variations on it, I'm quite a noob on media queries so I hope you can spot something thats off..

Comment: do you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag in your HTML's `<head>`?

Comment: I have this there:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

Comment: Other browsers/devices react to their media queries just fine...

Comment: When I see the code in IE11 it translates that media query as "@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), all and(-ms-high-contrast:active), all and (min-width:767px){

Comment: Does IE11 reask media query code when resizing?

Comment: I don't understand, if you are just trying to target screen larger than 767 then why use the high contrast stuff? You could just put all the IE 11 css in a separate file and use the IE conditional comments to use in IE11 only

Comment: My grid activates at >767 on all browsers, some browsers need the new grid code and IE11 needs the older -ms-grid code, you're saying I could create 2 files, with one giving support to IE11 and the other one to all other browsers right? But I would have to get that min-width statement working there as well if someone resizes their browser to below 767 right?

Comment: I just want to make sure IE11 doesn't read code inside that media query when the user goes below 767

Comment: then what is the point of the `-ms-high-contrast` part? have you tried without it?

Comment: No other browser is going to care about the `-ms-grid` properties you specify, so why do you need to limit your media query based on `-ms-high-contrast` to begin with …?

Comment: You don't have grid-gap in -ms-grid so you will have to add some extra code for it that is not needed in other browsers. A lot of Nokia Lumia's are still around in Finland and some of them use Internet Explorer as their browser too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have tested everything, supporting grid/-ms-grid/no-grid, I see that the best way is this:

1. Create mobile friendly html5 site without grid
2. Support Internet Explorer 11 by doing this:

   ```
   @media screen and (min-width: 767px){
       *::-ms-backdrop,.example{
           display: -ms-grid;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Support "display: grid;" enabled browsers with this:

   ```
   @media only screen and (min-width: 767px){
       @supports (display: grid){
           .example{
               display: grid;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Remember to make sure the code is in this order because Edge still reads the old grid code aswell.

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon, since links can die. Please quote the important part into your answer and explain.